# It surprised me his not inviting you to the wedding party. Is this sentence grammatically correct?

Tags: grammaticality

I came across this sentence in a book. It's an example of "it" as a preparatory subject. What I didn't understand is the part " his not inviting ". It sounded weird to me. If it's correct, then how? If it's not, then what is the correct sentence?

Comment: Yes. it is correct. It is the possessive + gerund. The "it" is a dummy subject.

Comment: Uh. I'm sorry. I have just learned we can use gerunds like nouns. So there is no question left in my mind about possessive plus gerunds. Thanks anyway.

Comment: The rule that inserts the _it_ is called Extraposition. It is normally used on infinitive subjects, but it can apply to gerund subject clauses, too, especially if they're long and complex like _his not inviting you to the wedding party_. _His_ is the subject of _not inviting you to the wedding party_; it could have been _him_ -- they're both acceptable for gerund subjects. You can't use gerunds like nouns, btw; you can use **gerund clauses** as nouns - the gerund itself is just the main verb form of the clause, not the whole structure it's in.

Comment: @JohnLawler thx for the thorough explanation.